# python matplotlib: how to move the scale to the other side of the axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have this weird thing with the scale of the axis showing out of the figure like:
[image]

And what I want to have:
[image]
How can I move the scale to the other side of the axis?

```
x=range(len(ticks))
plt.plot(x,phase1,'r^-',label='$\Delta \phi(U1,I1)$')
plt.plot(x,phase2,'go-',label='$\Delta \phi(U2,I2)$')
plt.plot(x,phase3,'b*-',label='$\Delta \phi(U3,I3)$')
plt.xticks(x,ticks,rotation=45)
plt.xlabel('Messung')
plt.ylabel('$\Delta \phi [^\circ]$')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: What about that image is not right? Can you include more description about the desired behaviour? Do you want to move the y axis completely to the right hand side of the image?

Comment: Do you want the y-axis ticks to be on the right side of the figure, or do you want the ticks and tick labels to be *inside* of the figure frame?

Comment: thx please see the new edition

Comment: I want the ticks inside of the figure frame yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `plt.tick_params()` to adjust the behaviour of the ticks, documentation can be found [here](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params.html).

For your example you want the ticks to appear inside the figure. Therefore add

```
plt.tick_params(direction="in")
```

to your code. Example:

```
x=range(len(ticks))

plt.plot(x,phase1,'r^-',label='$\Delta \phi(U1,I1)$')
plt.plot(x,phase2,'go-',label='$\Delta \phi(U2,I2)$')
plt.plot(x,phase3,'b*-',label='$\Delta \phi(U3,I3)$')

plt.xticks(x,ticks,rotation=45)
plt.xlabel('Messung')
plt.ylabel('$\Delta \phi [^\circ]$')
plt.legend()

plt.tick_params(direction="in") # Set ticks inside the figure

plt.show()
```

You can get the ticks to appear on the top and right side of the figure too as shown in your second screenshot by adding:

```
plt.tick_params(direction="in",top="on",right="on")
```

If you wanted to make *all* figures in your Python script have this behaviour then you can add the following at the top of your script ([this](https://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html) might be of interest):

```
import matplotlib

matplotlib.rcParams['xtick.direction'] = "in"
matplotlib.rcParams['ytick.direction'] = "in"
```

This will save you having to call `plt.tick_params()` for each figure, which is helpful if you generate lots of figures.

Answer (score 2):

The `tick_params` of your axis can be used to control axes label and ticks location. Set direction to in so that they point into the graph.

And [here](https://matplotlib.org/examples/api/two_scales.html) is a great example if you want different y-axis ranges and colours too.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.tick_params(direction='in', length=6, width=2, colors='r', right=True, labelright='on')

plt.show()
```

[image]