# Matplotlib: different scale on negative side of the axis

Tags: matplotlib, multiple-axes

**Background**

---

I am trying to show three variables on a single plot. I have connected the three points using lines of different colours based on some other variables. This is shown here [image: figure here]

---

**Problem**

---

What I want to do is to have a different scale on the negative x-axis. This would help me in providing positive x_ticks, different axis label and also clear and uncluttered representation of the lines on left side of the image

---

**Question**

---

- How to have a different positive x-axis starting from 0 towards negative direction?
- Have xticks based on data plotted in that direction
- Have a separate xlabel for this new axis

---

**Additional information**

---

I have checked other questions regarding inclusion of multiple axes e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9103166/multiple-axis-in-matplotlib-with-different-scales)  and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44925543/python-matplotlib-how-to-move-the-scale-to-the-other-side-of-the-axis). However, these questions did not serve the purpose.

**Code Used**

```
font_size = 20
plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': font_size})

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
#read my_data from file or create it

for case in my_data:

    #Iterating over my_data

    if condition1 == True:
        local_linestyle = '-'
        local_color = 'r'
        local_line_alpha = 0.6
    elif condition2 == 1:
        local_linestyle = '-'
        local_color = 'b'
        local_line_alpha = 0.6
    else:
        local_linestyle = '--'
        local_color = 'g'
        local_line_alpha = 0.6

    datapoint = [case[0], case[1], case[2]]

    plt.plot(datapoint[0], 0, color=local_color)
    plt.plot(-datapoint[2], 0, color=local_color)
    plt.plot(0, datapoint[1], color=local_color)
    plt.plot([datapoint[0], 0], [0, datapoint[1]], linestyle=local_linestyle, color=local_color)
    plt.plot([-datapoint[2], 0], [0, datapoint[1]], linestyle=local_linestyle, color=local_color)
plt.show()
exit()
```

Comment: Your example picture is nice. Could you please post the code you used to make it?

Comment: updated the question to include the code used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a custom scale, where values below zero are scaled differently than those above zero.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import scale as mscale
from matplotlib import transforms as mtransforms
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter

class AsymScale(mscale.ScaleBase):
    name = 'asym'

    def __init__(self, axis, **kwargs):
        mscale.ScaleBase.__init__(self)
        self.a = kwargs.get("a", 1)

    def get_transform(self):
        return self.AsymTrans(self.a)

    def set_default_locators_and_formatters(self, axis):
        # possibly, set a different locator and formatter here.
        fmt = lambda x,pos: "{}".format(np.abs(x))
        axis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(fmt))

    class AsymTrans(mtransforms.Transform):
        input_dims = 1
        output_dims = 1
        is_separable = True

        def __init__(self, a):
            mtransforms.Transform.__init__(self)
            self.a = a

        def transform_non_affine(self, x):
            return (x >= 0)*x + (x < 0)*x*self.a

        def inverted(self):
            return AsymScale.InvertedAsymTrans(self.a)

    class InvertedAsymTrans(AsymTrans):

        def transform_non_affine(self, x):
            return (x >= 0)*x + (x < 0)*x/self.a
        def inverted(self):
            return AsymScale.AsymTrans(self.a)
```

Using this you would provide a scale parameter `a` that scales the negative part of the axes.

```
# Now that the Scale class has been defined, it must be registered so
# that ``matplotlib`` can find it.
mscale.register_scale(AsymScale)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot([-2, 0, 5], [0,1,0])
ax.set_xscale("asym", a=2)

ax.annotate("negative axis", xy=(.25,0), xytext=(0,-30), 
            xycoords = "axes fraction", textcoords="offset points", ha="center")
ax.annotate("positive axis", xy=(.75,0), xytext=(0,-30), 
            xycoords = "axes fraction", textcoords="offset points", ha="center")
plt.show()
```

[image]

The question is not very clear about what xticks and labels are desired, so I left that out for now.

Comment: I need to have positive xticks and labels, also, for the x-axis I need separate xlabels one in positive and one in negative direction.

Comment: This is badass! I just wished there was a simpler way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to get what you want. This solution uses two twined `axes` object to get different scaling to the left and right of the origin, and then hides all the evidence:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
from numbers import Number

tickkwargs = {m+k:False for k in ('bottom','top','left','right') for m in ('','label')}

p = np.zeros((10, 3, 2))
p[:,0,0] -= np.arange(10)*.1 + .5
p[:,1,1] += np.repeat(np.arange(5), 2)*.1 + .3
p[:,2,0] += np.arange(10)*.5 + 2

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
host = fig.add_subplot(111)
par = host.twiny()

host.set_xlim(-6, 6)
par.set_xlim(-1, 1)

for ps in p:
    # mask the points with negative x values
    ppos = ps[ps[:,0] >= 0].T
    host.plot(*ppos)

    # mask the points with positive x values
    pneg = ps[ps[:,0] <= 0].T
    par.plot(*pneg)

# hide all possible ticks/notation text that could be set by the second x axis
par.tick_params(axis="both", **tickkwargs)
par.xaxis.get_offset_text().set_visible(False)

# fix the x tick labels so they're all positive
host.set_xticklabels(np.abs(host.get_xticks()))

fig.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Here's what the set of points `p` I used in the code above look like when plotted normally:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
ax = fig.gca()
for ps in p:
    ax.plot(*ps.T)
fig.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Could you please help in setting up x-axis labels. One in positive direction and one in negative direction e.g. say 'foo' in x positive and 'zoo' in x negative.

Answer (score 0):

The method of deriving a class of `mscale.ScaleBase` as shown in other answers may be too complicated for your purpose.
You can pass two scale transform functions to `set_xscale` or `set_yscale`, something like the following.

```py
def get_scale(a=1):  # a is the scale of your negative axis
    def forward(x):
        x = (x >= 0) * x + (x < 0) * x * a
        return x

    def inverse(x):
        x = (x >= 0) * x + (x < 0) * x / a
        return x

    return forward, inverse

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

forward, inverse = get_scale(a=3)
ax.set_xscale('function', functions=(forward, inverse))  # this is for setting x axis

# do plotting
```

More examples can be found in [this doc](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/gallery/scales/scales.html).